# JSON NULL AL CARGAR NUEVOS DATOS

Tags: python, json, tkinter

tengo un archivo json que es:

```
[
    {
        "Id": 1,
        "Servidor": "Servidor1",
        "IP": "1.1.1.1",
        "Estado": "Activo"
    },
    {
        "Id": 2,
        "Servidor": "Servidor2",
        "IP": "2.2.2.2",
        "Estado": "Inactivo"
    },
    {
        "Id": 3,
        "Servidor": "Servidor3",
        "IP": "3.3.3.3",
        "Estado": "Activo"
    },
    {
        "Id": 4,
        "Servidor": "Servidor4",
        "IP": "4.4.4.4",
        "Estado": "Activo"
    }
]
```

**Cuando quiero cargarle nuevos datos, me aparece Null, luego en el archivo json. Como hago para que si guarde los datos??? Este es el archivo python.**

```
from tkinter.ttk import *
from tkinter import *
import json
##############################################################################################
ventana = Tk()
ventana.geometry("575x500")
ventana.title("Ejercicio N°8")
##############################################################################################
tipotexto = "Comic Sans MS", 12, "italic"
tipotitulo = "Comic Sans MS", 12, "italic", "underline"
##############################################################################################
Label(ventana, background="Brown1", text="~ VictoriaVMC", font=tipotexto,
      justify=CENTER).pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=BOTH, expand=False)
##############################################################################################
with open('servidores.json') as f:
    diccionarioInformatica = json.load(f)
##############################################################################################


def menu():
    Radiobutton(ventana, text="4 - Ver todos los servidores.",
                value=4, variable=seleccion, command=MostrarDatos, font=tipotexto).place(x=60, y=170)
    Radiobutton(ventana, text="5 - Ingresar un nuevo servidor.",
                value=5, variable=seleccion, command=MostrarDatos, font=tipotexto).place(x=60, y=200)

def cantidadServidores(pContar):
    contar = 0
    for listas in diccionarioInformatica:
        for clave in listas:
            if clave == pContar:
                contar += 1
    return contar


def mostrarListas():
    Label(ventana, font=tipotitulo, text="Id").place(x=40, y=260)
    Label(ventana, font=tipotitulo, text="Servidor").place(x=110, y=260)
    Label(ventana, font=tipotitulo, text="IP").place(x=275, y=260)
    Label(ventana, font=tipotitulo, text="Estado").place(x=350, y=260)
    contador = 20
    for lista in diccionarioInformatica:
        for clave, valor in lista.items():
            if clave == 'Id':
                Label(ventana, text=valor, font=tipotexto,
                      justify=CENTER, width=3).place(x=65, y=260+contador)
            if clave == 'Servidor':
                Label(ventana, text=valor, font=tipotexto).place(
                    x=190, y=260+contador)
            if clave == 'IP':
                Label(ventana, text=valor, font=tipotexto).place(
                    x=300, y=260+contador)
            if clave == 'Estado':
                Label(ventana, text=valor, font=tipotexto).place(
                    x=410, y=260+contador)
                contador += 30


def MostrarDatos():
    separador = "☆…☆…☆…☆…☆…☆…☆…☆…☆…☆…☆…☆…☆…☆…☆…☆…☆…☆…☆"
    Label(ventana, width=100, height=15).place(x=10, y=230)
    Label(ventana, text=separador, font=tipotexto).place(x=40, y=230)
    Label(ventana, text=separador, font=tipotexto).place(x=40, y=440)

    opcion = seleccion.get()

    buscarSegun = "Servidor"
    if opcion == 4:
        mostrarListas()
    else:
        cargarNuevo = cantidadServidores(buscarSegun)
        listadeJson = cargarNuevosServidores(
            diccionarioInformatica, cargarNuevo)
        with open("servidores.json", "w") as jsonfile:
            json.dump(listadeJson, jsonfile)

def cargarNuevosServidores(plistadeJson, NumeroNuevo):
    diccionarioP = dict()
    ident = NumeroNuevo + 1
    diccionarioP["Id"] = ident
    concatenaServidor = (f"Servidor{ident}")
    diccionarioP["Servidor"] = concatenaServidor
    concatenaIP = (f"{ident}.{ident}.{ident}.{ident}")
    diccionarioP["IP"] = concatenaIP
    Label(ventana, text="En que estado se encuentra? \n 1. Activo \n 2. Inactivo",
          font=tipotexto, justify=CENTER).place(x=100, y=270)
    r1 = IntVar()
    Entry(ventana, font=tipotexto, textvariable=r1, width=15).place(x=280, y=300)

    def tipoEstado():
        carga = True
        estado = r1.get()
        if estado == 1 or estado == 2:
            mensaje = "Carga realizada con exito!"
            if estado == 1:
                estad = "Activo"
            else:
                estad = "Inactivo"
                diccionarioP["Estado"] = estad
            plistadeJson.append(diccionarioP)
        else:
            carga = False
            mensaje = " ERROR DEBE INGRESAR: \n 1-ACTIVO O 2-INACTIVO"
        Label(ventana, text=mensaje, font=tipotexto,
              width=25, height=2).place(x=150, y=390)
        if carga:
            return (plistadeJson)

    Button(ventana, font=tipotexto, text="Cargar",
           command=tipoEstado).place(x=250, y=350)


#############################################################################################
seleccion = IntVar()
menu()
ventana.mainloop()
```

Acá se ve el error NULL, luego de ejecutar y seleccionar la 5ta opción. Solo por seleccionar el 5 ya queda Null, no es necesario de ponerle algún estado...

[image: Acá se ve el error NULL, luego de ejecutar y seleccionar la 5ta opción. Solo por seleccionar el 5 ya queda Null, no es necesario de ponerle algún estado...]

Me pide que publique más detalles, pero explique todo ya. Deberían de quitar esto... porque es alto embole pero bueno... Si alguien sabe cuál es mi error, agradecería me avisen.

Comment: Me parece que nunca le cargas algo ```plistadeJson``` en ```CargaNuevosServidorea``` y como no retorna nada le pone ```None```  en la linea ```listadeJson = cargarNuevosServidore```

Comment: Supongo que deberías hacer un ```return diccionarioP``` y en ves de asignar poner un append: listadeJson.append(cargarNuevosServidores...l

Comment: Hay varias fallas en el código, las principales: el `null` es porque `listadeJson` está esperando un valor de retorno que nunca llega. La función interna `tipoEstado` está retornándole a donde fue llamada, por lo que hay una especie de loop entre el `Button` y la función interna `tipoEstado`. Recomiendo crees una función para escribir el JSON, y la llames cuando la necesites.